# How to get permission again,when delete file in external SD-Card

Tags: android

I used  the follow code :

```
private void handleTreeAction(Intent data){
    Uri treeUri = data.getData();

    final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
    & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);

    mRoot = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);

    showToast(" open tree uri "+treeUri);
}
```

I can get the permission,and write and delete file,all is Ok.But when I delete one file,and create new file,i dismiss the permission,How to get the permission again? I donot want to show permission dialog again and again.

Comment: It is unclear where handleTreeAction is called from and what that uri should be. Please start your post telling which action intent you used.

Comment: `.takePersistableUriPermission(uri ....` uri? What does it have to do with treeUri ?